# How to implement locking in a shared cachecontroller?

Tags: c#, caching, locking

I have a static class which handles the cache read/write for frequently used data.

The code is this:

```
 public static T GetFromCache<T>(double seconds, string cacheId, Func<T> method) where T : class
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
        object temp = null;
        temp = ctx.Cache[cacheId];

        if (temp == null)
        {
            lock (Sync)
            {
                temp = ctx.Cache[cacheId];
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    temp = method.Invoke();
                    AddToCache(temp as T, seconds, cacheId);
                    return temp as T;
                }

            }
        }

        if (temp is T)
        {
            return (T)temp;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

The code is used by various callers to read data from and write data to the cache.
Now I have a Sync object (`private static readonly object Sync = new object();`) which gets locked when data gets written to the cache.

As this code is called by multiple callers, I would like to create a List of Sync objects, one for each caller. (with caller I don't mean the user, but calling code. I then would identify a `caller` by the signature of the parameter `method`)
The reason I want this is that every  piece of calling code can have it's own lock object; otherwise (I think) every call to this cachecontroller from different callers will use the same lock object. Then, the caching for the list of countries will also lock the caching of the list of states, and with two different lock objects, they will not be in each others way.

I would then use the `CacheItemRemovedCallback` method to remove the lockitems from the list.

The question is this: How can I do that?

Comment: Is it possible for multiple users to be writing to the cache simultaneously?

Comment: Yes, could be. We also use it for lists of data for dropdowns, so it could be 2 users are hitting the method at the same time

Comment: Im having difficulty understanding why you need a list of sync objects

Comment: I edited the question, hope this makes things clear

Comment: Again, is this cacheId unique globally or just unique per 'caller' ?

Comment: Each caller has it's own cacheid and it's own data-retrieve method, but could be called multiple times at the same time of course.

Answer (score 1):

By having one Sync object for each user will defy the purpose of synchronization as each use will hold its own lock and there will be a chance that for the same cacheId you will end up invoking the method multiple times. This might result in data becoming inconsistent.

If you wish to keep one Sync object per user then it's good to make use of session variables or per user cache or something similar.. otherwise each user will virtually end up messing up with each other's cacheId results.

If you have a scenario when there can be Multiple readers of data but at a time a single user can write it then try using ReaderWriterLockSlim. This is very fast compared to lock in a multi user scenario.

**Update1**

Considering the cacheId is unique and not common among the callers. You can use the following code.

No lock is needed here. Reason, HttpContext.Cache is ThreadSafe. Meaning, you can read/save values to Cache. But, if the value reference itself is being shared among more than one concurrent calls, then please synchronize it.

```
 public static T GetFromCache<T>(double seconds, string cacheId, Func<T> method) where T : class
        {
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            object temp = null;
            temp = ctx.Cache[cacheId];
            if (temp == null)
            {
                temp = method.Invoke();
                AddToCache(temp as T, seconds, cacheId);
                return temp as T;
            }
        }
```

Regards

Comment: Hi, I see I was not so clear an what I meant with the `caller`; I edited the question for this.